# Get command coloured output in a variable

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to get command's original coloured output in a variable that i can print.

I have following script:

```
#Colors
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

# Runing test cases
res=$(script -q /dev/null mocha $(find "tests/non-ui" -name "*.js")) #Command that runs test cases
RESULT=$?
[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && echo -e "$res ${RED}Some TestCaes did not pass. Please check your code.${NC}" && exit 1
echo "All test cases passed.\n"
exit 0
```

It gives me following output:

```
Some TestCaes did not pass. Please check your code.:13:16)
```

where `:13:16)` part is some last characters of output of this command `res=$(script -q /dev/null mocha $(find "tests/non-ui" -name "*.js"))`.

Running `mocha $(find "tests/non-ui" -name "*.js")` this command alone gives following output:

```
  All element creation test:
    1) Label


  0 passing (16ms)
  1 failing

  1) All element creation test: Label:

      AssertionError: false == true
      + expected - actual

      -false
      +true

      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/non-ui/sample-test.js:13:16)
```

How can i get whole output in a variable?

Comment: @Ravexina here is my problem statement.

Comment: I don't think your question has anything to do with coloured output. It is about capturing command output and put it in another command. To that end, it's not clear what you mean by 'whole output'. Is it the whole output from `mocha $(find "tests/non-ui" -name "*.js")`?

Comment: @biocyberman, you are right. I have another script(previous version of this script) where this command `res=$(script -q /dev/null ./tests/ui-test)` runs as i expect (`./tests/ui-test` file contains `$( mocha $(find "tests/non-ui" -name "*.js"))` ). This let me capture coloured output of a command written in `tests/non-ui` file. when i run `res=$( mocha $(find "tests/non-ui" -name "*.js"))` without `script` command. It gives me proper output but all formatting, indentation and colours are gone.

Comment: So later on i thought that combining these two `script` and `mocha` command will give me all output with colors but it gives only some characters of last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add double quotes around your commands:

```
res="$(script -q /dev/null mocha $(find "tests/non-ui" -name "*.js"))"

echo "$res"
```

This will preserve the ANSI colors.

Comment: it is already in quotes `"$res ${RED}Some TestCaes did not pass. Please check your code.${NC}"`.

Comment: Yes, but nor your command res="..."